# (Proof verification) differentiable function is Lipschitz on a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

On wikipedia, there is a counter-example for this statement.
$f(x) = x^{3/2} \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ defined on $[0, 1]$ where $f(x) = 0$ is not Lipschitz since its derivative is not bounded.

Previously, I attempt to prove the wrong statement as follows and I am not sure where I was wrong in this.

**wrong attempt:** Proving all differentiable functions on a compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is Lipschitz

Suppose a differentiable function $f$ is not Lipschitz on $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. That is there exists two sequences $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}, (y_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \in K$ such that
$$
||f(y_k) - f(x_k)|| > k ||y_k - x_k||
$$
By Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, the two sequences have convergent subsequences $(x_{k_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \to x, (y_{k_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \to y$.

If $x \neq y$ use the same argument in [1], there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > N, ||y_{k_n} - x_{k_n}|| > ||y-x||/2$, therefore
$$
||f(y_{k_n}) - f(x_{k_n})|| > k_n||y_{k_n} - x_{k_n}|| > k_n ||y - x|| / 2
$$
That is $f(K)$ is unbounded. Contradiction

If $x = y$, as $f$ is differentiable at $x$, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $z \in B_\delta(x), ||f(z) - f(x) - L(z - x)||$ where $L = f'(x)$ with its norm $||L||$ being finite.
Furthermore, $(x_{k_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \to x, (y_{k_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \to x$ implies that, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{k_n}, y_{k_n} \in B_\delta(x), x_{k_n} \neq y_{k_n}$ for all $n > N$. We can bound the difference between $f(y_{k_n})$ and $f(x_{k_n})$ by

\begin{align*}
||f(x_{k_n}) - f(y_{k_n}) - L(y_{k_n} - x_{k_n}) ||
&= ||[f(x_{k_n}) - f(x) - L(x_{k_n} - x)] - [f(y_{k_n}) - f(x) - L(y_{k_n} - x)] || \\
&\leq ||f(x_{k_n}) - f(x) - L(x_{k_n} - x)||+ ||f(y_{k_n}) - f(x) - L(y_{k_n} - x)|| \\
&< 2\epsilon
\end{align*}

So,
$$
2 \epsilon
 > ||f(x_{k_n}) - f(y_{k_n})||  - ||L(y_{k_n} - x_{k_n}) || \geq ||f(x_{k_n}) - f(y_{k_n})||  - ||L||.||y_{k_n} - x_{k_n} ||
$$
Combine with the premise,
$$
2\epsilon > (k_n - ||L||) ||y_{k_n} - x_{k_n}||
$$
Choosing $n$ large enough yields a contradiction

[1] https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2338876/700122

Comment: Where is the contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot that $||y_{k_n}-x_{k_n}|| \to 0$ as $n$ becomes large (they converge to the same point, $x$ (equal to $y$)). You cannot ensure that the term $k_n ||y_{k_n}-x_{k_n}||$ blows up.